# Using nested scss rules in Gatsby scss modules

Tags: sass, css-modules

In React I have a component called `GlobalFooter`, that provides a website footer.
The component has nested HTML elements.

My scss module looks something like this:

```
.GlobalSiteFooter {
    background-color: #1e6ed0 ;
    a.footer-logo {
        border: 2px solid #000 ;
    img {
       }

    }
}
```

When Gatsby processes the component, it adds strings to class names, in order to keep the CSS scoped to the component.

However, it doesn't add a string to the element footer-logo.

It does add a string to the CSS rule 'a.footer-logo'.

As a result, nested rules within SCSS files cannot be applied to their target elements.
As far as the browser is concerned, the targeted elements don't exist.

Is there a way to nest SCSS rules, and have those rules applied to their corresponding DOM elements?